# Mumbai to london - dubai change of planes

Tags: visas, transit

I have a flight from mumbai to London with 3 hrs layover(change of planes at Dubai), both Mumbai to dubai and dubai to london flight is of Emirates only and terminal is also same. (T3)

do i reuqire transit visa for the same?

Comment: did not understand - possible duplicate of what?

Comment: It's saying this question is a possible duplicate of that previous question. Please follow the link.

Comment: Many people change planes in Dubai, so many people want to know if they need a transit visa. We've compiled a standard answer for this question.